# Why doesn't this xargs + grep combo work properly?

Tags: linux, unix, grep, xargs

I have two files, team1.txt and team2.txt

```
team1.txt
===========
Alex 
Bob
Charlie
David
```

```
team2.txt
===========
Alex
Charlie
Benjamin
Zed
Noah
```

I want to output the people who are in both team1 and team2 using a unix command.

```
$ cat team1.txt | xargs grep -s team2.txt -e
team2.txt:Alex
```

The problem is that this is incorrect. Both Alex AND Charlie are in team1 and team2. But for some reason `grep` stops after the first match. Why is this? `xargs` should be running grep on every line from `team1.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your Alex in team1.txt has a trailing space, and
the one in team2.txt doesn't.  That said: why don't you just use

```
grep -f team1.txt team2.txt 
Alex
Charlie
```

This works (I cleaned up the extra space) well, and only requires
one command invoked once.

Comment: You're right, it works now! The trailing space... The reason I can't use your command above is because the original problem wasn't as simple as the example I gave - team2.txt has a bunch of other text on each line with the name in it.

Comment: Still, the fact that you can do that is good to know :-)